# tcpdump filter sequence number

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I have captured a packet trace and would like to write a script that will allow me to isolate a matching pair of acknowledgement and Sequence packets(no other way to filter out all the other packets) so that I can then work out the Round Trip Time(RTT) between 2 computers

The problem I am having is that I can't filter the 2 packets based on their ACK and Sequence numbers

It needs to be doable with tcpdump but scripting languages such as awk are ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `proto[x:y]` form of filtering in tcpdump to do this.

[RFC 793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) tells us that the sequence number starts at byte 4 of the TCP header, and the acknowledgement number at byte 8; both are 4 bytes long.

So you can look for packets that both have sequence and acknowledgement numbers `123456` like this:

```
tcpdump -r capturefile tcp[4:4] = 123456 or tcp[8:4] = 123456
```

You need to use the absolute seq/ack numbers to do this, as tcpdump is matching the values against the raw data in the packet.  Use `tcpdump -Sr filename` to display your capture file with absolute sequence numbers.

Comment: it doesn't work :/ it doesn't give an error but it also doesn't display the timestamps for the 2 packets like it's supposed to

this is the actual command where it's being used 

student@ubuntu:~$ tcpdump -r '/home/student/Downloads/trace1.dump' -n tcp[4:4] = 25993 or tcp[8:4] = 16417 | cut -c1-15

I've tried removing 1 at a time in case 1 of them was causing the problem but it didn't change anything

if I remove both it lists all of the timestamps

if I keep the filters but remove the cut command it doesn't help

Comment: Are you definitely using the absolute and not relative seq/ack numbers?  Find your packet with `tcpdump -Sr filename`.  The seq/ack numbers should be much longer than the ones you've given.